# Azure IoT Edge ModuleClient invoke direct method in another module

Tags: c#, azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk, azure-iot-edge

I'm using the Azure IoT Edge runtime running Linux containers on a Windows host OS.
I have two modules, ModuleA and ModuleB. ModuleA have a registered direct method called "MethodA" and ModuleB have a registered direct method called "MethodB".

When I invoke MethodA I want the method to invoke MethodB located in another module  (but running in the same IoT Edge runtime).

I'm using the Azure IoT SDK for c# and
in the Init() function of ModuleA I have:

```
await ioTHubModuleClient.SetMethodHandlerAsync("MethodA", MethodA, ioTHubModuleClient);
```

And in the Init() function of ModuleB I have:

```
await ioTHubModuleClient.SetMethodHandlerAsync("MethodB", MethodB, null);
```

The MethodA (that acts like a proxy method):

```
static async Task<MethodResponse> MethodA(MethodRequest methodRequest, object moduleClient)
    {
        try 
        {
            ModuleClient ioTHubModuleClient = (ModuleClient)moduleClient;             

            // Get deviced id of this device, exposed as a system variable by the iot edge runtime
            var deviceId = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("IOTEDGE_DEVICEID");

            // Create the request
            MethodRequest request = new MethodRequest("MethodB", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{ \"Message\": \"Hello\" }"));

            // Execute request
            var resp = await ioTHubModuleClient.InvokeMethodAsync(deviceId, "ModuleB", request);

            return resp;               
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            return await Task.FromResult(new MethodResponse(500));
        } 
    }
```

The MethodB that I try to invoke from MethodA:

```
private static Task<MethodResponse> MethodB(MethodRequest methodRequest, object userContext)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MethodB has been called");

        // Get data but we do not do anything with it
        var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(methodRequest.Data);

        Console.WriteLine("Received data: " + data.ToString());

        var methodResponse = new MethodResponse(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{\"status\": \"ok\"}"), 200);
        return Task.FromResult(methodResponse);
    }
```

Note that I can invoke these two methods separately just fine from the azure portal or by using the Azure SDK for C# -> ServiceClient class.

My program crashes on the line

```
var resp = await ioTHubModuleClient.InvokeMethodAsync(deviceId, "ModuleB", request);
```

in MethodA and in the VS Code debugger I get the exception

> Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Exceptions.IotHubCommunicationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll

And when I check the logs for my Message/StackTrace-print I get:

> An error occurred while sending the request.
>      at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Transport.HttpClientHelper.d__21.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Transport.HttpClientHelper.d__172.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.ModuleClient.d__57.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult()
>      at OrderGateway.Program.d__3.MoveNext() in /app/Program.cs:line 92

I've tried to initialize the ModuleClient using both Amqp with TCP/WebSocket_Only as well as Mqtt with TCP/WebSocket_Only.
I've also tried to run the IoT Edge runtime with these modules on a Ubuntu 18.04 VM without any success.

Even when I try to invoke a method located in the same module with the ioTHubModuleClient.InvokeMethodAsync() I get the same exception / stacktrace...

I also tried to invoke the MethodB from the Init() function of ModuleA to try and not invoke a direct method in the context of a callback but I do get the same exception.

There is an open issue on github that you can find here: https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/issues/204

But it feels that it have kind of stalled and I don't get any help.

From my understanding this should be possible but I don't know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

I just made this scenario to work, but It's a little bit different than your description.

So, here is what I did: 
1-Created 2 Modules, ModuleA and ModuleB; 
2-Added your MethodA on ModuleA and your MethodB in Module B; 
3-On Module B (Not ModuleA), I added this code:

```
       while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Invoking method On moduleA");
                var deviceId = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("IOTEDGE_DEVICEID");
                MethodRequest request = new MethodRequest("MethodA", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{ \"Message\": \"Hello\" }"));

                var response = await ioTHubModuleClient.InvokeMethodAsync(deviceId, "ModuleA", request).ConfigureAwait(false);
                Console.WriteLine($"Received response with status {response.Status}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error invoking method {ex}");
            }

            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
```

That is it. At the begin you will get an exception like this one:

Error invoking method Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Exceptions.DeviceNotFoundException: Device {"message":"Client angelodTransparentGateway/ModuleA not found","exceptionMessage":"","status":0,"payload":null} not registered
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Transport.HttpClientHelper.ExecuteAsync(HttpMethod httpMethod, Uri requestUri, Func`3 modifyRequestMessageAsync, Func`2 isSuccessful, Func`3 processResponseMessageAsync, IDictionary`2 errorMappingOverrides, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Transport.HttpClientHelper.PostAsync[T1,T2](Uri requestUri, T1 entity, IDictionary`2 errorMappingOverrides, IDictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.ModuleClient.InvokeMethodAsync(Uri uri, MethodRequest methodRequest, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at ModuleB.Program.Init() in /app/Program.cs:line 74

But this is by design, and it's just because it takes time for modules to be created after a deployment, but in less than 1 minute I was able to get the succesfull result:

MethodA has been called
Received data: {"Message":"Hello"}

If you call MethodB from ModuleA the MethodA won't get called. But just to make sure it worked I also tested module A invoking Module B. Here is the code:

```
        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Invoking method On moduleB");
                var deviceId = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("IOTEDGE_DEVICEID");
                MethodRequest request = new MethodRequest("MethodB", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{ \"Message\": \"Hello\" }"));


                var response = await ioTHubModuleClient.InvokeMethodAsync(deviceId, "ModuleB", request).ConfigureAwait(false);
                Console.WriteLine($"Received response with status {response.Status}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error invoking method {ex}");
            }

            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
```

Both Worked. 
Don't forget to use .NET version 2.1 (Update that on your dockerfile).

Comment: Thanks for your help.  When you say _Don't forget to use .NET version 2.1 (Update that on your dockerfile)_. Do you mean changing the _<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>_ to _<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>_ in the respective module .csproj file? That's what I did but now I get: ```C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.202\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(135,5): error : The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.1.```

Comment: @NoExit, I have verified this issue, as Angelo said, change the dotnet runtime as 2.1, it works. If you use linux container, you should set `microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build-env` & `microsoft/dotnet:2.1-runtime` in Dockerfile.windows-amd64 file.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelXu-MSFT and what if I use windows containers? Should I set these variables to the same then as well? I'll try and get this to work asap.

Comment: @NoExit, yes, if you use windows contianer, you should set the same value in Dockerfile.windows-amd64.

Comment: @MichaelXu-MSFT Your example above now works fine when invoking the method from Init() like you did. Although when trying to do the same from within another direct method callback I do get the error: Device {"Message":"{\"errorCode\":404001,\"trackingId\":\"ID\",\"message\":\"Device unavailable\",\"timestampUtc\":\"TIMESTAMP\"}","ExceptionMessage":""} not registered. Please see my follow up question at: https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/issues/204 Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: @MichaelXu-MSFT I felt that this could be a separate question so I opened up a new issue here: https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/issues/337